# Einstein's equivalence principle (EEP) and indefinite acceleration

Tags: general-relativity, acceleration, equivalence-principle

My first question was going to be:

Does EEP hold at all time scales?

I believe this was successfully answered at [Einstein's Principle of Equivalence - Infinite Acceleration/Energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/243658/einsteins-principle-of-equivalence-infinite-acceleration-energy)

The answer is no, but it does not claim to. Einstein's equivalence principle says that gravitational and inertial acceleration are locally indistinguishable from each other. The key being "locally" in space and in time.

Nonetheless, while considering this problem, the question arises: what happens to a craft that is accelerated indefinitely? I recognize that this is somewhat physically unrealistic, but imagine using some extraordinarily bright and continuous stationary photon source to impart momentum to the craft. I assume that this constant input of energy would eventually cause the object to collapse into a black hole! Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Einstein's equivalence principle says that gravitational and inertial acceleration are locally indistinguishable from each other.

Correct. Constant acceleration is completely indistinguishable from a perfectly uniform gravitational field, but no real gravitational field is perfectly uniform, so there are tidal effects if you make measurements over a large enough distance. When we say "locally indistinguishable" it means you confine your measurements to a chunk of spacetime that's small enough in the given gravitational field so that it looks like flat spacetime, and then the tidal effects are negligible.

> what happens to a craft that is accelerated indefinitely

If you apply uniform acceleration to a craft, that is, the acceleration feels like constant gravity to the people in the craft, then its speed gets closer and closer to *c* without ever reaching it. That may seem weird, but it works that way because of the relativistic formula for [velocity addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula). For further details, please see the classic Usenet [Relativistic Rocket](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html) page.

> I assume that this constant input of energy would eventually cause the object to collapse into a black hole! Is that true?

No, that's not true. Even if the speed of the craft is a tiny fraction just under lightspeed, so the crew are experiencing a huge time dilation relative to the rest frame they took off from, they won't notice anything unusual, although their view of the universe will change due to length contraction and Doppler shift.

However, if such an ultra-relativistic craft crashed into something, that *could* create a black hole, but the required kinetic energy is incredibly high. Eg, if you could turn all the energy of a dozen Earths colliding with a dozen antimatter Earths into kinetic energy, and used that energy to slam two billiard balls into each other, it could create a black hole, providing the collision fragments stay close enough to the collision point.

Comment: In the high energy billiard ball collision example, I assume this effect occurs because the particles composing the billiard ball experience such a large impulse by the sudden deceleration of collision, so as to overcome the repulsive forces (and quantum mechanical prohibitions of distance) normally keeping the constituent particles of mass at normal-life space-separation distances, resulting in a configuration of elementary particles at the same inter-particle separation as is seen/predicted for a black hole?

Comment: @Thomas Not really, although that's part of what's going on. The main thing is that gravity (i.e., spacetime curvature) is proportional to the stress-energy-momentum in a region. If we can concentrate sufficient energy into a small enough region we get a black hole. A black hole with a Schwarzschild radius equal to a billiard ball has a mass about a dozen times that of Earth. Merely giving a billiard ball that much kinetic energy won't  create a black hole: the billiard ball is still just a billiard ball in its rest frame.

Comment: But smashing two such balls gives us enough energy in the centre of mass frame of the two balls. However, we lose roughly half of the kinetic energy we pumped in due to the gravitational waves that are emitted as the black hole forms.

Comment: In theory, we could make a black hole with no matter at all, just using the energy of light. Obtaining such an intense concentration of light is far beyond our technical capabilities, but it has a name: [kugelblitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kugelblitz_(astrophysics)).

Comment: Thanks, you offer an interesting addition to the concept - that the collision produces a shock wave/gravitational wave, and that roughly half of the energy is lost as gravitational radiation.  I assume this amount of energy loss is a prediction from GR, and it would vary slightly with the duration-of-impulse?

Comment: "If we can concentrate sufficient energy into a small enough region we get a black hole." Isn't that exactly what we are doing when we accelerate something indefinitely. I agree with your point that the billiard ball is still just a billiard ball in its own rest frame. What I find confusing is that in MY rest frame, eventually its relativistic mass will exceed that required to form a black hole. How can I reconcile these two very different outcomes?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I don't know the fine details (such calculations are beyond my skills), I got that figure of 50% in a related conversation some time ago. The basic idea is that any changes to the gravitational field corresponding to the [quadrupole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole#Gravitational_quadrupole) or higher moments must emit gravitational waves. Forming a black hole by smashing 2 bodies together causes very intense changes to spacetime curvature, so a lot of energy is dissipated as gravitational waves.

Comment: @burgerking I agree that it can seem hard to reconcile. The kinetic energy of a body doesn't mean much when the body is isolated, since any body is traveling at 0.999999c in *some* frame. If a body is a black hole in some frame, it must be a black hole in *every* frame, you can't create (or destroy) a BH by mere mathematical manipulation. So kinetic energy is relevant when you have 2 or more objects with different speeds, then you can talk about the kinetic energy of one body relative to another, or the KE of each body relative to the centre of mass of the collection of bodies.

Comment: @burgerking You may find this article by John Baez on [torsors](http://www.math.ucr.edu/home/baez/torsors.html) helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the discussion and link, I am still confused. Let us imagine a rock in frame A. In frame B, a spacecraft, having been accelerated for a billion years, is travelling at relative speed very close to light speed. The spacecraft collides with the rock, and as discussed (hypothetically at least) this could create a black hole. In this picture, the spacecraft is rapidly accelerated from one frame into another. How is this fundamentally different from a spacecraft that is slowly accelerated from one frame to another over a billion years of acceleration at a few g?

Comment: @burgerking Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but it doesn't matter how quickly the ship and the rock acquire their speeds. All that matters is what their relative speed is when they collide.

Comment: But a collision is just a fast acceleration into another frame. My question is why that differs from an acceleration spread out in time. I'm not a relativity expert, but I imagine there is a frame where the collision looks like a billion years of slow acceleration.

Comment: @burgerking The rate of acceleration involved in the collision isn't really relevant. The ship & the rock have different velocities in different frames, but all observers will calculate the same energy of impact involved in the collision. If the energy density in a region of space (strictly speaking, the stress-energy-momentum) is greater than or equal to the Schwarzschild limit, then a black hole forms.

Comment: @PM 2Ring. Thank you for your answers. I'm not sure if I am making myself clear or if I fully understanding what you are saying. Based on your last comment, it seems like it is indeed possible to create a black hole by accelerating an object for a very long time. After all, the acceleration itself is nothing but a series of many many collisions that impart energy. And in some frame, that looks like a catastrophic, nearly instantaneous event.

Comment: @burgerking No, it isn't possible to create a black hole by just accelerating an object for a very long time. Those relatively small collisions in the rocket engine don't have a lot of energy or momentum in the centre of mass frame of the rocket + exhaust.

Comment: @burgerking OTOH, I've been assuming that the rocket is accelerating in a perfect vacuum, but even deep intergalactic space contains some atoms (and photons). Eventually, the ultra-relativistic rocket will be going so fast that the momentum of the collisions with those atoms & photons will become significant, and that friction will make it very difficult for the rocket to continue accelerating, no matter what sort of propulsion mechanism we use.